# AWS Elastic Beanstalk NPM error on deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ejs

I'm running my frontend on an AWS EC2 instance and use Code Pipeline to Deliver my code to deployment. While execution I get this error and my current build fails to execute beyond this point. But in my local host everything works as expected.

Here's the error from my `/var/log/eb-engine.log`

```
2021/06/11 15:54:30.130038 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm config set jobs 1
2021/06/11 15:54:30.726850 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm --production install
2021/06/11 15:55:25.517929 [INFO] 
> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /var/app/staging/node_modules/@surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread/node_modules/ejs
> node ./postinstall.js


2021/06/11 15:55:25.520296 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 244. Stderr:
 

2021/06/11 15:55:25.520730 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/06/11 15:55:25.529146 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: You didn't specify a Node.js version in the 'package.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version.","timestamp":1623426870,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment: 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1623426925,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1623426925,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2021/06/11 15:55:25.535409 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy
```

I am using a t2.micro instance on EC2.

Comment: What is happening in your deployment file (ie, before the npm install --production) ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue with npm install command in AWS instance.
Use npm install --only=prod (or --only=production). If npm version is greater than v3.3.0

Before v3.3.0 of npm (2015-08-13), the option was called --production, i.e. npm install --production.

Comment: I have tried this and added a Procfile to run a deploy script which does npm install --only=prod but I still get the same error 8/10 times I try to deploy.